# Android sqlite database design using triggers

Tags: android, database, sqlite, triggers

I need to design a sqlite DB for an Android application.

Use Case: I have 2 tables A, B.

A has 4 columns _id, roll_no, name, Marks.

B has 4 columns roll_no, past_score, current_score, expected_score.

With every record added to this table i need to make a network request by sending Marks. The response of this request needs to be parsed and populated in the columns past_score, current_score, expected_score of table B.

Can you please guide me as what would be the best approach to design the DB?
I have heard of Triggers (never used it before) which could be used to maintain data integrity and foreign key constraint. Can i use trigger for the use case mentioned above or do i need to populate both the tables independently ?

Pardon me if this question sounds silly.

Comment: What is the idea behind splitting it into two tables? It seams to me that one table is more reasonable.

Comment: There are also other columns involved. I have mentioned only the relevant columns to keep it simple. Both the tables are used independently by 2 different modules.

Comment: AFAIK in Android triggers can be used only to update db. You cannot use a Sqlite trigger to do non db tasks

Comment: Thanks Nandeesh. If not trigger what else ?

Comment: Go through with following link it expalins step by step process
http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842/0/page/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The android way of doing things with data is to use the ContentProvider class.

It's not the easiest of things to implement but it gives a great deal of flexibility.

You could for example fire an intent to an intentservice when a row is inserted, which, in turn, downloads what you need and insert those records using the same contentprovider.

Think of it as a data broker.  It handles all CRUD requests.

Comment: Thanks Merlin. This should solve my problem.